# How can I combine these two queries? (where in clause)?

Tags: sql, join

```
Select * 
FROM Products as a 
join ProductTags as b 
on (a.ProductId = b.ProductId)
join Tags as c 
on (b.TagId = c.TagId)
where c.TagName = 'FISH'

Select * 
FROM Products as a 
join ProductTags as b 
on (a.ProductId = b.ProductId)
join  Tags as c 
on ( b.TagId = c.TagId)
where c.TagName = 'STEAK'
```

I know there is probably a fairly easy solution but I cannot figure it out

I want to get all of the products that have an entry in the ProductTags table for both 'Tags'.

new queries

Original:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductTags as a 
JOIN Tags as b on (a.TagId = b.TagId)
WHERE b.TagName = 'FISH'

SELECT * 
FROM ProductTags as a 
JOIN Tags as b on (a.TagId = b.TagId)
WHERE b.TagName = 'STEAK'
```

Solution
    SELECT a.ProductId 
    FROM ProductTags as a
    JOIN Tags as b on (a.TagId = b.TagId)
    WHERE b.TagName in ('FISH', 'STEAK')

I think i need a HAVING clause? Idk

Comment: I think I understand this as a [relational division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-division) problem. In cases like this, it's best to include some sample data and expected results to really show others what you're looking for.

Comment: Okay thanks McAdam331.  I'll make sure to do that next time.

Comment: Of course it's always recommended, but looking over the other answers I can see that this question can be interpreted differently, and without seeing samples and expected results, not everyone will interpret it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something called relational division, which I just brought up on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281023/what-can-we-do-to-prevent-repeated-relational-division-questions) earlier today. You can use a subquery for this. The outer query will pull all rows that match 'Fish' and the inner query will select from that only the rows that also match 'Steak'. Try this:

```
SELECT a.product_id
FROM producttags a
JOIN tags b ON b.tagid = a.tagid
WHERE b.tagname = 'Fish' AND a.product_id IN(
   SELECT a.product_id
   FROM producttags a
   JOIN tags b ON b.tagid = a.tagid
   WHERE b.tagname = 'Steak'
```

**EDIT**

To add other tags, if necessary, you can add more `IN` operators to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT a.product_id
FROM producttags a
JOIN tags b ON b.tagid = a.tagid
WHERE b.tagname = 'Fish' 
   AND a.product_id IN(
      SELECT a.product_id
      FROM producttags a
      JOIN tags b ON b.tagid = a.tagid
      WHERE b.tagname = 'Steak')
   AND a.product_id IN(
      SELECT a.product_id
      FROM producttags a
      JOIN tags b ON b.tagid = a.tagid
      WHERE b.tagname = 'Chicken')
```

Comment: This works! You da man.  Thanks for helping me out!  I see exactly how that works.  Thats great. Thanks!

Comment: What if I wanted to add a third tag, like 'CHICKEN'?

Comment: @user1977591 just add another condition to your outer query. See edit to answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you only want to query the `Tags` table in your subqueries to avoid the overhead of the `JOINS`? You only need the `TagId` which can be determined based `Tags.TagName`.

Comment: I'm trying to convert this query to linq now >_<

Comment: @user1977591 I dont know much about it. If youre still stuck later on, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You just need an `IN` condition:

```
Select * 
FROM Products as a 
join ProductTags as b 
on (a.ProductId = b.ProductId)
join Tags as c 
on (b.TagId = c.TagId)
where c.TagName IN ('FISH', 'STEAK')
```

You can add as many literals as you like in the `IN` clause as long as they are comma separated.

**Edit per the updated question:**

If you want to get all `ProductId` where multiple categories ore matched, you could do this:

```
SELECT ProductTags.ProductId
FROM ProductTags
WHERE 
    -- Pull all matches of FISH
    ProjectTags.TagId IN (SELECT TagId
                          FROM Tags
                          WHERE TagName = 'FISH')
    AND
    -- Pull all matches of STEAK
    ProjectTags.TagId IN (SELECT TagId
                          FROM Tags
                          WHERE TagName = 'STEAK')
```

Comment: I feel like this should work but I still get records that only have one of the TagNames and not both.  I actually slimmed down the query and it looks like this now. (see orig post)

Comment: @user1977591 - That's a different question. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all STEAKs and FISH, you can use a simple OR condition:

```
Select * 
FROM Products as a 
join ProductTags as b 
on (a.ProductId = b.ProductId)
join  Tags as c 
on ( b.TagId = c.TagId)
where c.TagName = 'STEAK' OR c.TagName = 'FISH'
```

Comment: This won't work. It will still return values that have one tagname or the other, but not *both*